# How can I see emails sent with Python's smtplib in my Outlook Sent Items folder?

Tags: python, outlook, smtplib

I am using hosted exchange Microsoft Office 365 email and I have a Python script that sends email with smtplib. It is working very well. But there is one issue, how can I get the emails to show up in my Outlook Sent Items?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was possible without enormous effort, but am looking forward to suggestions from other users.

Comment: Here's a (somewhat confused) support forum thread on the subject: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/160/t/73713.aspx .

Answer (score 2):

You can send a copy of that email to yourself, with some header that tag the email was sent by yourself, then get another script (using IMAP library maybe) to move the email to the Outlook Sent folder

Comment: That's a start all right. With some trickery and email filtering it should work... Thanks for the tip.